# Encryption and Decryption Java Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, netbeans

I have created simple encryption program to encrypt any input file and save it in new output file. At this moment I get simple encryption result however I want to use following pattern as the encryption of the text in the file.

each letter with a number corresponding to the position of the letter in the alphabet  
 each digit with the first letter of the name of the number

After the encryption will be done and working I would like to try on the decryption of the text.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class CaesarCipher
{
   private int key;

   public CaesarCipher(int key)
   {
      this.key = key;
   }

   public char encrypt(char ch)
   {
      return (char)(ch + key);
   }

   public void encryptFile(Scanner in, PrintWriter out)
      throws IOException
   {

      while(in.hasNextLine())
      {
         String line = in.nextLine();
         for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
         {
            char ch1 = line.charAt(i);
            char ch2 = encrypt(ch1);
            System.out.print(ch1);
            out.print(ch2);
         }
         if(in.hasNextLine())`enter code here`
            out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. I read it, and could not understand what you are asking. As far as I can tell, you are reading from prompt, and writting in a `PrintWriter` somewhere. What is the problem?

Comment: HI, is the updated question better? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From the ascii code table [ascii-code](http://www.ascii-code.com/), we know the ascii code of each digit and of each letter. You can use that to do the following in your `encryptFile` method:

1. Create a switch or an enum to map each digit to the first character of it's name. Ex: 0 to 'z', 1 to 'o', 2 to 't', etc...
2. Check if ch1 is a digit by doing the following: `if (ch1 >= 0x30 && ch1 <= 0x39)`.
3. If true, then ch1 is a digit. Retrieve the letter corresponding to the digit from your mapping, and display it.
4. Same for a letter: `if (ch1 >= 0x61 && ch1 <= 0x7A)`.
5. If ch1 is a letter, then you can convert the hex value of ch1 to an integer using `Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)` (ex: 'a' will be 97) and subtract a constant 96 from it). So, for 'a' you'll display 1 (97-96=1), and for 'd' you'll display 4 (100-96=4). This way you will get the position of the letter.
6. Similarly, you should handle upper-case letters.

There are many different ways of achieving what you are trying to do. This is one of them. It's not necessarily the best one.